# How to say "martlet" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests, terminology

A [martlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martlet) is:

> ... a heraldic charge depicting a stylized bird similar to a swift or
>   a house martin, with stylized feet.

"Martlet" is not present in my Chinese dictionary, and Google Translate does not produce any results.

So how can I write "martlet" in Chinese?

Context: I am describing the appearance of a martlet in the coat of arms of a particular university.

Comment: http://www.iciba.com/martlet https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E6%97%A0%E8%B6%B3%E9%B8%9F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an extremely specialised field; I have no better suggestions than to describe it literally:

無足鳥像的寓意物

*A charge depicting a martlet.*

> Reference:
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

martlet /märtlət/

If there's no official translation, you can always use transliteration.  For example 瑪勒鳥 (Mǎ Lēi bird)

Or you can call it '無足燕' , based on the description "swallow without feet"

Edit:

seems like user3306356 had found the official translation of martlet-- '无足鸟'(no feet bird) ; But I wonder, if it is a kind of swallow, why not call it '無足燕'(no feet swallow)?

*学名岩燕 (scientific name:rock swallow), may be '岩燕' is a better choice?*

Answer (score 0):

**[无足鸟](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E8%B6%B3%E9%B8%9F)**

> 无足鸟，又称圣马丁鸟，学名岩燕，居住在山岩峭壁之上。 因此人们看不到它们休息，只见到圣马丁鸟无休无止的在空中飞翔，一生艰辛，因此有了无足鸟的美丽传说。